# How to get standard deviation of last n rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an OHLC csv loaded in pandas dataframe. I am trying to get last n rows' std. I am looping through df. Here is what i have done so far:

```
df['std'] = np.zeros([len(df), 1])
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df['std'][i] = df['Close'][-(i+ln):i].std()
```

EDIT:

To be clear, i need last n row's std of each row. Let's say my row index is 100 and n is 25. I need 75:100 std and need to apply this to each row. Here is my solution but this is a long way i think:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if i > ln-2:
        end = -(clen-i)
        begin = end - ln
        df['std'][i] = df['Close'][begin:end].std()
```

Comment: Can you put a sample of your dataframe and the result that you would wish to have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas DataFrame `rolling` function. In your example I am not sure if you want just std of last n rows, or in i-th row of `df['std']` you want to have std of rows from (i-n)-th to i-th of `df['Close']`.

Second option can be done like this:

```
df['std'] = df['Close'].rolling(n).std()
```

Comment: Isn't it going to give me whole dataframes std()? I need std of last n rows of each row

Comment: So std of which rows you want to have in i-th row of `df['std']`? This solution in i-th row has std of rows from (i-n+1)-th to i-th

Comment: I need n'th row of Close. So for example 100 th Close's std will be std of [75:100]

Comment: This is exactly what my solution does. You must read `DataFrame.rolling` documentation to set good parameters, for example if window where you compute std should be right closed or not, bo I am sure that you need rolling function
 (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Answer (score 3):

I think that might work

```
df.tail(n).std()
```

Comment: but this only gives last n's std. I need last n from each row

Comment: ah sorry my bad. it gives only last n rows std

Comment: you need the std for each row of the last n rows?

Comment: try add axis=1 to std
    df.tail(n).std(axis=1)

Comment: which error did you get?
did you set the number of last rows?